# Implement a function that returns the longest sequence of either 1s or 0s and the first index of it

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

I need write a function that return the longest sequence of either 1s or 0s for a given array (of 1s and 0s). It also needs to return in a pointer the index at which this longest sequence begins.

Say for example I have the array

```
a[]={1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1}
```

The function returns

```
3, 1
```

where 3 is the longest sequence (in this case of 0s) and 1 is the index at which it begins.

What I did was this:

```
int longestSequence(int a[], int n, int* begin)
{
int count=1;
int max_length=1;
int i;

for(i=1;i<n;i++)
{
    if(a[i]==a[i-1])
    {
        count+=1;
    }
    else if (count>max_length)
    {
        max_length=count;
        count=1;
    }
    else
    {
        count=1;
    }
}

if(count>max_length)
   {
       max_length=count;
   }
return max_length;
}
```

I tried a couple of examples to see if the function returns the longest sequence and it works. However, I'm unable to find a way to return the right index at which it begins.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Make a structure containing 2 members, one being `int` as the length of the sequence and other one being `*int` as the pointer to the beginning of the sequence. Then, make a function that returns that structure

Comment: Save the value of `i` in the `else` case. Record that saved value into `*begin` in the `else if` case.

Comment: Keep a running tally of the currently found max sequence index and length, if you find any longer sequence, update tally with new info. Return result.

Comment: BTW, there are more problems in your code than just that so suggest you do more testing. For example, `a[i+1]==a[i]` will cause a buffer overflow on the last iteration (when `i` is `n-1`)

Comment: Also, I assume that `int n` is the length of `a[]`, right? If so, your `for(i=0;i<n;i++)` loop tries to access the value that is not in an array. Consider this: `a[3] = {0, 0, 0}` `n = 3`. Here, in your for loop, if `i` is 2, in your if statement (`if(a[i+1]==a[i]`) you are trying to access `a[3]` which is beyond the range of an array.

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys but I tried a couple more examples now and looks like my code isn't returning the right longest sequence. I tried running the array 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1  and its returning 7 instead of 5 for the longest array. I need check this again.

Comment: That's because if you reach end of array, you are not checking if the current sequence that's being checked is the longest one. Just make one more `if` statement after you finish your `for` loop

Comment: Also, because you init the `count` to 1 instead of 0.

Comment: Hello. I took your suggestions and updated my code in the post. What do you think about it now?

Comment: I took out a pen and paper and tried this again though. Seems to work. :P

Comment: this statement: `It also needs to return in a pointer the index at which this longest sequence begins.` is not possible, either return a pointer to the appropriate address in the string.  OR return the index into the stirng.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
int longestSequence(int a[], int n, int *begin){
    int i, count, max_length = 1;
    *begin = 0;

    for(i = 0; i + max_length < n; i += count){
        for(count = 1; i + count < n && a[i] == a[i + count]; ++count)
            ;
        if(count > max_length){
            max_length = count;
            *begin = i;
        }
    }
    return max_length;
}
```

Comment: You are undoubtedly a legend. You've helped me a lot in the past. Can you please tell me what you think of the code I updated above (before adding the *begin)?

Comment: Nice.  Note: corner case oops: `longestSequence(0, 0, &begin)` returns `1`.

Comment: @chux You declared `int a[0];` But C standard forbids zero-size array.

Comment: @FlyGuy I think your code gives the correct length.

Comment: `int a[]` is like `char *`. Would  `longestSequence(NULL, 0, &begin)` be a better corner case? My example did not declare `int a[0]`.  If you do not want to handle this case - no problem - OP likely does not care about it either.

Comment: @chux I think that's a meaningless call.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thank you. Do you have an idea as to how I would add in it the *begin?

Comment: @FlyGuy My answer is intended as an idea. I think that is sufficiently concise. In the case of your idea I think that it will be back calculated from the break place.

Comment: `i + max_length < n` is a neat shortcut

Answer (score 0):

your code nearly works.

add `max_index = i - count;` just below `max_length=count;`  (both places)

also define `int max_index;` near the top.

Answer (score 0):

Try this small edit:

```
int longestSequence(int a[], int n, int* begin)
{
int count=1;
int max_length=1;
int out_index = 0;
int i;

for(i=1;i<n;i++)
{
    if(a[i]==a[i-1])
    {
        count+=1;
    }
    else if (count>max_length)
    {
        max_length=count;
        out_index = i - count;
        count=1;
    }
    else
    {
        count=1;
    }
}

if(count>max_length)
{
       max_length=count;
       out_index = i - count;
}
*begin = out_index;
return max_length;
}
```

Comment: I did. It doesn't work. Take for example 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1. It will return that the sequence begins at 3 which is not correct.

Comment: Nevermind. I had the order of the count and out_index wrong in the loop. I think it works now. Thank you!

Comment: Btw, I also omitted the last else as it doesn't change a thing.

Comment: the else at the end takes care of the case where the longest sequence was at the end of the array, for example - {0,0,1,0,0,0}

Comment: I just tried it on a piece of paper and you're right. It keeps the count the same as it was without resetting it as it doesn't enter any if condition. However, the code seems to work just fine with or without omitting it. I wonder why...